# Count rows who aren't null (minute interval) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to count rows for every minute that aren't null using Entity Framework.
In one minute can be more rows with variable hodnota1 = 1(int).

[image]

Result is 6.

I need count how many minutes are with one or more 1 variables in Hodnota1.

```
public float RunPercent(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    var countMinutes = db.ESP_LOG.Where(t => t.Time > start && t.Time < end).GroupBy(xxx).Count();
    return countMinutes;
}
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: You're going to need to elaborate here for this to be answerable. What is a "1" variable? What precisely is null, presumably a particular property of an entity? A row itself cannot be null - which is what your title claims. Why is your result called "percent", since you're not doing a percent calculation? An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help tremendously here. The entity class definition, an example data set, and an expected result set would make it clear what it is you're looking for.

Comment: Also, `return var;` isn't valid syntax, but that may just be a typo in the question rather than in your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the logic you need is.  But the in SQL you can divide up a time range into intervals with the DATEDIFF function.  So something like:

```
var logEntriesByMin = db.ESP_LOG.Where(t => t.Time > start && t.Time < end)
                .GroupBy(t => EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(new DateTime(1970, 01, 01), t.Time))
                .Select(g => new
                {
                    WindowStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01).AddMinutes(g.Key),
                    WindowMinTime = g.Min(t => t.Time),
                    TotalRows = g.Count(),
                    NonNullRows = g.Sum(t => t.SomeProp.HasValue?1:0),
                    NullPercentage = (g.Count() - g.Sum(t => t.SomeProp.HasValue ? 1 : 0)) / g.Count()
                });
```

Will return one row per minute, for each minute having any rows, along with statistics over the rows in that minute.